# Reload all UIViewControllers in each UINavigationController of UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab based application and I want to update the information that is displayed in all UIViewControllers reloading them when I click in a button.

I have tried several ways to refesh the view controllers like [view setNeedsDisplay] and [view setNeedsLayout] but without success. I had also iterate all navigation controllers of tab bar and it's view controllers and applied this function calls without no success too.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` most likely has nothing to do with what you want to do here (but we can't be positive). What do you mean by "update the information that is displayed"? That is a very broad phrase.

Comment: I have several info displayed in view controllers (labels, table views...) that are directly related with the choose that the user makes on the button that I mention, so I want to reload the entire view controllers, but without having to release and recreate them.

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` is not what you are looking for. What do you mean "reload"? I assume you set content in these `UIViewControllers` somewhere (e.g. in the case of a label, by doing `[label setText:@"Some Text"]`) - you have to do that again, otherwise, how is the `UIViewController` supposed to know what content to display?

Comment: The content is dynamic, I have tags for it and it changes as I click on the button. My question is if exists a way of force the view controllers to update it's subviews all at once like they do when I create its instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically add this to all controllers you want to refresh :

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshAllViews:) name:@"RefreshAllViews" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)refreshAllViews:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Reload all the data and views you want here
    // eg. [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)reloadAllViewsAction:(id)sender
{
    // Call this from the button to refresh all views
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RefreshAllViews" object:nil userInfo:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:
(1) Use `notification`, when user clicks the button, send a notification(Maybe with some informations), so that all the `view controllers` which are interested in that notification could update itself accordingly;
(2) Store the information in a shared `model` (`Singleton`) so it can be accessed by all the `view controllers`, and for each view controller, update UI in `viewWillAppear` according to that shared `model`